# Is it possible to calculate 255 factorial in 8085 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, factorial, 8085

I am wondering if it is really possible to create an 8085 assembly language program that calculates the value of 255 factorial. What I have done so far is 18 factorial max.

Comment: You can, but 255! has 505 decimal digits, so you'll need to implement some routines for handling arbitrary precision integer arithmetic (at least for multiply and add).

Comment: @PaulR  what do you need the add for? ;)

Comment: @Tommylee2k: my bad - just multiply then! ;-)

Comment: just found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416483/how-to-find-a-factorial ... the `log(i)/log(10)` version is neat

Comment: yes. (but not trivial)